# R function to add a hierarchical column in order from multiple rows to columns?

Tags: r, tapply, data-transform

I'm using the below sample data as my input.

5 Columns -  1) Part_ID  2)Station_ID  3)Time  4)Parameters  5)Values

Sample.CSV
[image]

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Part_ID</th><th>Station_ID</th><th>Time</th><th>Parameters</th><th>Values</th></tr><tr><td>A_01</td><td>S_01</td><td>4/30/19 3:00 PM</td><td>ABC_01</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>A_01</td><td>S_01</td><td>4/30/19 3:05 PM</td><td>ABC_02</td><td>12</td></tr><tr><td>A_01</td><td>S_01</td><td>4/30/19 3:10 PM</td><td>ABC_03</td><td>11</td></tr><tr><td>A_01</td><td>S_01</td><td>4/30/19 3:15 PM</td><td>ABC_04</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>A_01</td><td>S_02</td><td>4/30/19 3:20 PM</td><td>XYZ_01</td><td>15</td></tr><tr><td>A_01</td><td>S_02</td><td>4/30/19 3:25 PM</td><td>XYZ_02</td><td>9</td></tr><tr><td>A_01</td><td>S_02</td><td>4/30/19 3:30 PM</td><td>XYZ_03</td><td>11.5</td></tr><tr><td>A_01</td><td>S_02</td><td>4/30/19 3:35 PM</td><td>XYZ_04</td><td>12.5</td></tr><tr><td>B_01</td><td>S_01</td><td>4/31/2019  3:00:00 PM</td><td>ABC_01</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>B_01</td><td>S_01</td><td>4/31/2019  3:06:00 PM</td><td>ABC_02</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>B_01</td><td>S_01</td><td>4/31/2019  3:12:00 PM</td><td>ABC_03</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>B_01</td><td>S_01</td><td>4/31/2019  3:18:00 PM</td><td>ABC_04</td><td>4.5</td></tr><tr><td>B_01</td><td>S_02</td><td>4/31/2019  3:24:00 PM</td><td>XYZ_01</td><td>5.5</td></tr><tr><td>B_01</td><td>S_02</td><td>4/31/2019  3:30:00 PM</td><td>XYZ_02</td><td>9</td></tr><tr><td>B_01</td><td>S_02</td><td>4/31/2019  3:36:00 PM</td><td>XYZ_03</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>B_01</td><td>S_02</td><td>4/31/2019  3:42:00 PM</td><td>XYZ_04</td><td>7</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I want to transform this data into below output data format as attached,

[image]

But When I tried to use `tapply()` function in R to transform my input data,

```
Sample_Data = read.csv("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Sample.csv")

OutPut_Table = with(Sample_Data, tapply(Sample_Data$Value,
                                              list(COMPOSE_ID=Sample_Data$Part_ID , PARAMETERS=Sample_Data$Parameters)                                            , tail, 1))
```

I'm getting the data as

[image]

Could you help me in how to add the hierarchical columns (Station_ID & Time) in between each set of parameters columns. Thanks

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not helpful. Share data in a reproducible format so we can run and test code.

Comment: Updated the input data

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a question of going from "long" format to "wide" format. There are a number of ways of doing this. I like the `reshape2` package, which uses the `cast()` function to go from long format to wide format. Since there's no reproducible example here, I'll just point you to some informative materials, like the reshape2 [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/reshape2.pdf) and [this helpful blog post](https://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape/).